# Application Domains with Proprietary DLL

Tags: c#, asp.net, marshalling, appdomain, appdomainsetup

I have an ASP.NET C# application that needs to execute code that is in a proprietary DLL in another app domain. It seems most code that I could find requires that I make the objects `MarshalByRefObject` but since they are in another dll, I don't really have access to them. I would like to ideally just make calls to the proprietary dll in another AppDomain, but I don't really know how I would go about doing that.

Comment: Add reference to that assembly.

Comment: Not sure what you trying to do... Do you need to "create AppDomain and run code there" OR "run my code in AppDomain magically created by some other assembly"?

Comment: I have created an AppDomain and am attempting to load the other assembly into it. I saw in examples that I should put `MarshalByRefObject` on the classes I want to marshall, but I can't since those methods are in the other dll.

Comment: Create serializable proxy calss and load that proxy into your new domain. Load your assembly from that proxy. `dom = AppDomain.CreateDomain("xxx");ObjectHandle h = dom.CreateInstanceFrom(Application.ExecutablePath, "YourProxyClass"); YourProxyClass proxy = h.Unwrap() as YourProxyClass; proxy.Domain = dom;` Now call `proxy.ExecuteSomething();` Your proxy knows how to use reflection to execute stuff